# R/Splus: Run set of functions repeatedly with different variables

Tags: r, function, apply

I want to be able to run the same functions repeatedly, across a suite of paired variables.  I have read other posts, and they suggest using the lapply function to do such a process, but I cannot get that to work in this case, likely because of my limited understanding of how to implement the appropriate "apply".

Here's the code I have.  You can see that it properly creates the text to run the functions (held in formulas.ccf and formulas.lagplot) and the proper variable for assignment (held in varnames), but how do I implement the functions and assign them to the appropriate varname?

```
names <- c("aran", "galv", "cc", "sa") #Names of the data vectors
cntr=1

varname <- array("",dim=c(9))
formulas.ccf <- array("",dim=c(9))
formulas.lagplot <- array("",dim=c(9))
for (i in 1:3){
 for (j in 2:4) {
  varname[cntr] <- paste("ccf",names[i],names[j],sep="_")
  formulas.ccf[cntr] <- paste("ccf(mydata$",names[i],", mydata$",names[j],",na.action=na.pass)",sep="")
  formulas.lagplot[cntr] <- paste("lagplot2(mydata$",names[i],", mydata$",names[j],",15)",sep="")
  cntr<-cntr+1
  }
  }

 varname 
 formulas.ccf 
 formulas.lagplot
```

Here one set of the code I wish to run; for this example varname="ccf_aran_galv", the ccf function="ccf(mydata$aran, mydata$galv,na.action=na.pass)" and the lagplot function="lag.plot2(mydata$aran_perc, mydata$galv_perc, 15)". This code would be run 9 times, once for each pair of variables:

```
ccf_aran_galv <- ccf(mydata$aran, mydata$galv,na.action=na.pass)
lag.plot2(mydata$aran_perc, mydata$galv_perc, 15)
```

I'm stuck, so would appreciate anyone's help.  I can obviously write out this code repeatedly, but would like to have a smaller coding footprint and increased flexibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to point you in the right direction, even though your example isn't totally reproducible.

If you're building R code as character strings with the hopes of then executing it, that is a big *big* sign that you're doing it wrong. There are times when it's necessary, but they are rare.

Another warning bell here is your fixation on `$`. There are other (better) ways of referring to the columns of data frames: `[` and `[[`. See `?Extract`. For instance, let's just look at the series of `ccf` calls you're trying to execute here. This would be a simple way of doing that:

```
#Assuming that mydata is a data frame with 4 columns
# named "aran", "galv", "cc", "sa".
results <- vector("list",9)
nm <- c("aran", "galv", "cc", "sa")
counter <- 1
for (i in 1:3){
    for (j in 2:4){
        results[[counter]] <- ccf(mydata[,nm[i]],mydata[,nm[j]],na.action = na.pass)
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
}
```

Note that I'm following your lead and indexing the columns of `mydata` my *character* by referring to a particular element in the vector `nm`. (I didn't call it `names` because that's a very common function.) But you could just as easily indexed them directly by position using `i` and `j` directly, assuming the columns are in the order you want.

Comment: You might want to do `for (j in (i+1):4)` to skip self pairs and repeated pairs.

Comment: OK, so this code does get me further than I was.  Guess I will dig into dataframes more so I can understand how to associate each CCF with a label.  In addition, I'm trying to send the graphical output from each pair to its own PDF -- labeled with the appropriate pair names, so I'm still fighting how that is implemented as well.